# What happens to $\theta_{CP}$ for ${\rm U}(1)$ in the Standard Model?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory, neutrinos, cp-violation

I'm trying to understand how we can get rid of the ${\rm U}(1)$ theta term (whose $\theta$ I call $\theta_1$) in the SM.

In Schwartz's QFT textbook he writes

> Before discussing the strong CP phase further, we note that the ${\rm SU}(2)$ and ${\rm U}(1)$ angles can be removed completely by chiral rotations. We saw that rotating only the right-handed fields can make the Yukawa couplings real, but $θ_2$ is unchanged by these rotations since right-handed fields are uncharged. Thus, we can rotate the left-handed fields only to put $θ_2$ into the Yukawa couplings then rotate the right-handed fields to remove it. Therefore, there is no basis-independent measure of CP violation for ${\rm SU}(2)$ and $θ_2$ is unphysical.
> Similarly, since neutrinos are uncharged, we can rotate them to show that the ${\rm U}(1)$ phase is unphysical. Thus, neither $θ_2$ nor $θ_1$ can have any physical consequences.

But this can't be right. Neutrinos are hypercharged so either he means U(1) of QED in which case the neutrinos are irrelevant or he means gauge-singlet right-handed neutrinos added to the SM. I could try to rephase left-handed neutrinos to set $\theta_1$ to zero, then on the neutrino mass terms I can remove the phases with the right-handed neutrinos - but won't I end up messing up the kinetic terms?

Comment: ? Right-handed neutrinos have no EM charge, thence no weak hypercharge, so they obey Matt's "right-handed fields are uncharged" glib mantra. Kinetic terms connect left with left and right with right, and so are rephrasing invariant. Where is the question?

Comment: @CosmasZachos My point is that kinetic terms connect neutrino to charged lepton, so that changing the phase of the neutrino alone would affect these terms.

Comment: Hypercharge is a U(1), whose covariant completion terms to kinetic terms *cannot* connect neutral to charged leptons!!

Comment: @CosmasZachos excellent thanks! I was mixing up electric and hypercharge when I was picturing this.

Comment: so you want to withdraw the question?